# appharbor gives error on compiling after push

Tags: asp.net, compilation, compiler-errors, appharbor

I get this error from appharbor:

```
Build started 5/31/2012 4:52:13 PM.
Project "D:\temp\woojnpbm.drx\input\wsolver.sln" on node 1 (default targets).
ValidateSolutionConfiguration:
  Building solution configuration "Release|Any CPU".
D:\temp\woojnpbm.drx\input\wsolver.sln.metaproj : warning MSB4121: The project configuration for project "wsolver" was not specified in the solution file for the solution configuration "Release|Any CPU". [D:\temp\woojnpbm.drx\input\wsolver.sln]
Project "D:\temp\woojnpbm.drx\input\wsolver.sln" (1) is building "D:\temp\woojnpbm.drx\input\wsolver.metaproj" (2) on node 1 (default targets).
Build:
  C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_compiler.exe -v /wsolver -p ..\..\WebSites\wsolver\ -u -f D:\temp\woojnpbm.drx\output\_PublishedWebsites\wsolver\ 
ASPNETCOMPILER : error 1003: The directory 'D:\temp\WebSites\wsolver\' doesn't exist. [D:\temp\woojnpbm.drx\input\wsolver.metaproj]
Done Building Project "D:\temp\woojnpbm.drx\input\wsolver.metaproj" (default targets) -- FAILED.
Done Building Project "D:\temp\woojnpbm.drx\input\wsolver.sln" (default targets) -- FAILED.

Build FAILED.

"D:\temp\woojnpbm.drx\input\wsolver.sln" (default target) (1) ->
(ValidateProjects target) -> 
  D:\temp\woojnpbm.drx\input\wsolver.sln.metaproj : warning MSB4121: The project configuration for project "wsolver" was not specified in the solution file for the solution configuration "Release|Any CPU". [D:\temp\woojnpbm.drx\input\wsolver.sln]


"D:\temp\woojnpbm.drx\input\wsolver.sln" (default target) (1) ->
"D:\temp\woojnpbm.drx\input\wsolver.metaproj" (default target) (2) ->
(Build target) -> 
  ASPNETCOMPILER : error 1003: The directory 'D:\temp\WebSites\wsolver\' doesn't exist. [D:\temp\woojnpbm.drx\input\wsolver.metaproj]

    1 Warning(s)
    1 Error(s)

Time Elapsed 00:00:00.62
```

My app is aspx.net 4.0 - anyone seen this before?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should probably check the paths in your solution and project files. From the error, `D:\temp\WebSites\wsolver\` is referenced, but that path is not found when your code is built on AppHarbor.

A good way to debug this would be to checkout or clone your code to a different machine to check whether it builds there.

Comment: Thanks found my mistake - I was pushing from the Project folder instead of the Websites folder under VS 2010. Now im live at [http://wsolver.apphb.com](http://wsolver.apphb.com)